# Flutter, how to set TabBar height?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

**Note :I have tried other answers on stackoverflow but they didn't work.**

I have a TabBar and want to set its height.

here is my code :

```
Widget getTabBar() {
    return TabBar(
      labelColor: LightTheme.TabIconColor,
      indicatorColor: LightTheme.TabIconColor,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
      tabs: [
        Tab(
            text: "Collect",
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_location,
              size: 40,
            )),
        Tab(
            text: "Deliver",
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.tour,
              size: 40,
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
```

and here is the screenshot of my app. As you can see the titles were clipped (the phrase "bottom overflowed by 22 pixels"):

[image]

and this is the rest of screen's code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Test'),
        backgroundColor: LightTheme.AppBarColor,
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            flexibleSpace: getTabBar(),
          ),
          body: getTabBarView(),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: getDrawer(),
      // Disable opening the drawer with a swipe gesture.
      drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
    );
  }
```

**Update :** I get the following message in the console. I tried to set BoxConstraint but the problem still exists:

```
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#fe401 relayoutBoundary=up25 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=173.7, 0.0<=h<=54.0)
...  size: Size(40.0, 54.0)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrap your `Tab` inside `Container` and set the height of the container. here is an example :

```
   Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Tab(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.add_location,
              size: 40,
            ),
            Text("Tab A"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

result:
[image]

Comment: it didn't work. I even add a column to the tab like you did but still have the same problem.